# How to properly implement feed(similar to Facebook/Instagram) in Android?

Tags: android, performance, caching, retrofit, picasso

I am very new to Android. I am trying to create a social app which contains lot of images and some metadata. It has a screen which is similar to the feed on Facebook. I want to make this screen as smooth and standard as possible.

Here are the libraries I am using: OkHttp, Picasso, Retrofit, Gson.

Right now, I am fetching all the json in one go, since I have seeded dummy values in backend and the response is small enough. But, in future, it will have the previous and next fields to limit the json response.

Some of the questions that I have right now:

1. I am using Picasso with OkHttp. Does that cache images in disk too or only in memory?
2. What are the best practices on caching the feed? Since the majority of content is images, should I just let Picasso handle the caching or should I cache some items on my own? Heard about DiskLruCache library from JakeWharton but not tried it. Should I go with it?
3. How to keep some feed contents(like 3 or 4) in either direction of scroll in cache so that scrolling appears smooth and that images don't start loading after coming in the view.
4. How to automatically handle json response using previous and next fields when the user scrolls all the content that was fetched in this one go. Basically I want to trigger requests based on the number of contents scrolled based on cursors.
5. Suppose there is a like button and the user click it, should I change the number of likes in the UI and side by send a POST request to update counter or should I send the request and wait for the updated counter from server before updating it in the UI?

I have already gone through the source code of [Instamaterial](https://github.com/frogermcs/InstaMaterial) and got to learn some amazing things. But it does not demonstrates the whole backend integration.

I just want to know if there are any other open source apps which I can study or learn from. If you know any tutorials that would help too. I just want to make the app experience as smooth as possible and want to learn some best practices.

Comment: On youtube there is a good series about this. look for "thenewboston"

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX they have a general android development series. If you are you referring to some particular videos, could you please post the links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. This will cache to disk as well as memory. If you set Picasso to debug mode it will display an indicator that describes where the image was loaded from (memory/disk/network)
2. If you don't mind Picasso having control over how long things are cached etc. then it should be fine to let it handle the caching. I'm also pretty sure that Picasso uses `DiskLruCache`
3. If your main concern here is the images, they will all be cached and shouldn't need to load after they have done so once (until it updates). You can also register a callback with Picasso in order to change the logic around showing or hiding placeholders.
4. I think that what you are looking for is a scroll listener on your listview (I assume you are using a list view). When it gets past a certain position (5/6) start loading the next 10. If you are using a recyclerview you can do this with the `onScrollStateChanged` function in the scroll listener and use the `LinearLayoutManager`to call `findLastVisibleItemPosition`
5. It shouldn't really matter which approach you go with. If you think that it will take a long time for it to update the server counter (which it shouldn't) then it is probably best to update it locally first.

Comment: for 4th point, suppose in a json response, I get 10 items and there are standard field for next and previous, which when attached to api query, will fetch the previous or next 10 items. how do I ensure that as soon as the user sees the 8th or 9th items and keeps scrolling(meaning he wants to see more items) I fetch next 10 items. It is similar scenario as in facebook app.

Comment: I have updated my answer with I think what you are looking for

Comment: Yes, precisely. Just one difference, I am using RecyclerView. I haven't seen or any written any code for the same. If you know of any good tutorial or explanation, please send across the link. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure of any good tutorials for what you are looking for. If you are looking to replicate the same functionality in a RecyclerView, this should do it
```recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
  {
   @Override
   public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
   {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    if(((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition() == 5)
//Load more items
   }
  });```

Answer (score 3):

1.I would suggest you to checkout **Image Management Library by Facebook** that is [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) that is pretty awesome and mature as compared to other Image Loading Library.

2.Fresco handles all the things caching of images with 3 Tier architecture ( `BITMAP_MEMORY_CACHE`, `ENCODED_MEMORY_CACHE` and `DISK_CACHE`). It also reduces OOM(Out Of Memory) issues. When image in a view goes out of screen it automatically recycles the bitmap, hence releasing the memory.

3.For that you have implement Pagination, yeah for sure you might have to send the previous record item position or index, so that you can fetch the items succeeding it.

4.For providing user the smooth experience in your app, you should increment the counter and send the post request to your backend simultaneously.

you can also checkout this tutorial [Facebook like Feed](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/).

Comment: I have checked out Fresco, but I found it's syntax to be a little complicated compared to Picasso and Glide. And Picasso does handle most of my needs efficiently. I will definitely give Fresco a try, if I encounter any performance loss using Picasso. Apart from the images, should I cache other metadata like username, number of likes using DiskLruCache? Also, since Picasso is doing caching of images itself, I don't need to cache them separately with DiskLruCache, do I?

Comment: @AmitTiwari yeah i said the samething in the beginning, but i prefer you to use it just now, because I had some problems with some JPG and PNG images. Picasso caused error, Fresco worked fine on the same images. so go ahead and use fresco from now.

Comment: @MBH I will check it out.

Comment: @AmitTiwari surely using Fresco is little bit complicated, but when you will start using it. you will understand its true power :)

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer you some approaches for some of your questions:

**For handling JSON**:

You can use library called [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), so adding and removing stuff in server side, will be easy to handle in your android client side. Just removing or adding variable in a Java class will be enough!

**For cashing images**:

I suggest you to use [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/), facebook library, It will ease your job alot. since it can handle rounded corner conversions, downloading Progress bars, Circular images and many more features. So, Not only handle the Memory and Disk cashing for you, but also works better with different image formats.

(I used picasso in my last project, Some pictures and some URIs did not work well, I tried Picasso, Glide, and Universal Image Loader, on exactly same image and same link..ONLY Fresco could work fine for me)

It is not exactly answer to your questions, however, i wanted to share my experience with those libraries that may help you.

Comment: Thanks. I will surely give Fresco a try.